# IOS photo upload low quality only sometimes

Tags: ios, photo-upload

I have an IOS app that uploads photos to a server. I need the highest quality photo available. On my personal device (Iphone4s IOS 8.1.1) this works every time. I always get the highest quality photo. However on a friends device (Iphone6 IOS 8.1.2) The photos are sometimes uploaded at low quality but not always (can be the exact same photo).

I have been chasing this bug for a while and have not been able to duplicate the problem on my device. So my question is are there any known issues that would cause this? or is it a problem with my code?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without code or at least more context

Comment: You bring up a good point. If the issue was related to IOS (such as a request for a photo returning a lower quality photo if memory is low) I was hoping someone would have mentioned any known issues not related to code. Judging by the lack of answers I assume its a problem with my code. I am going to get my friends device and trouble-shoot the issue. When I find and correct the issue I will post the exact cause of the problem.